# How to override remove_column method rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, overriding

I need to ovveride this methode to add caution when it use in production ENV !
like :

```
def remove_column(...)
  raise 'You will delete data with column !' if Rails.env.production?
  [... normal code ...]
end
```

Comment: Is this not something that should be handled by CI or just decent coding practices?

Comment: I mean your going to have to rewrite half of rails if you want to idiot proof it.

Comment: @max Precisely, those who code have made a mistake that has lost important data in prod ... In short, it does not help me much this kind of remark ^^

Comment: I believe you need to override https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L569 this method in an initializer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but maybe something like this?

## lib/schema_statements.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters 
    module SchemaStatements
      include ActiveRecord::Migration::JoinTable

      def remove_column(...)
        raise 'You will delete data with column !' if Rails.env.production?
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```